# Expand a function to allow unlimited paramters to be passed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created the following function which allows me to create a Simple SQL Command and pass up to 2 Parameters to it. I know I can just keep creating additional functions and add the extra parameters but am wondering if there is a simple way of adding an unlimited amount of Parameters. Thanks

```
''' <summary>
''' Create a simple SqlCommand object with 2 parameters.  Parameter Values always passed as a string
''' </summary>
''' <param name="cmdText"></param>
''' <param name="Param1Name"></param>
''' <param name="Param1Type"></param>
''' <param name="Param1Value"></param>
''' <param name="Param2Name"></param>
''' <param name="Param2Type"></param>
''' <param name="Param2Value"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function CreateSimpleSQLCommand(cmdText As String, Param1Name As String, Param1Type As ExpectedDataType, Param1Value As String _
                                             , Param2Name As String, Param2Type As ExpectedDataType, Param2Value As String) As SqlCommand
    Dim SqlCommand As New SqlCommand(cmdText, OpenASqlConnection)

    If Param1Name <> "" Then
        If Param1Type = ExpectedDataType.Int Then
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & Param1Name, CInt(Param1Value))
        ElseIf Param1Type = ExpectedDataType.Dec Then
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & Param1Name, CDec(Param1Value))
        Else
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & Param1Name, Param1Value)
        End If
    End If
    If Param2Name <> "" Then
        If Param2Type = ExpectedDataType.Int Then
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & Param2Name, CInt(Param2Value))
        ElseIf Param2Type = ExpectedDataType.Dec Then
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & Param2Name, CDec(Param2Value))
        Else
            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & Param2Name, Param2Value)
        End If
    End If
    Return SqlCommand
End Function
```

Comment: I would start by creating a class called Param, which contains the fields `ParamName`, `ParamType` and `ParamValue`, and pass a  `List` of this `Param`-class to the function. O wait, there is this thing called [SqlParam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You should do as suggested and either define your own type to represent a parameter or use the `SqlParameter` type, then declare a single parameter in the method as a `ParamArray`, e.g.

```
Public Sub ExecuteCommand(command As String, ParamArray parameters As SqlParameter())
```

You can then pass a single `SqlParameter` array as an argument or discrete `SqlParameter` objects.  You will have encountered a `ParamArray` before, possibly many times, e.g. in the `String.Format` method.